# Rails FactoryGirl for model that belongs_to 2 other models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, factory-bot

I have 3 following models like this:

```
# model/timeline.rb
class Timeline
  belongs_to :series
  belongs_to :creator
end

def series_belongs_to_creator
  if creator_id
    creator = Creator.find_by id: creator_id
    related_series = creator.series.find_by id: series_id
    errors.add(:series_id, :not_found_series) unless related_series
  end
end

# model/creator.rb
class Creator
  has_many :timelines
  has_many :series, through: :contents
end

# model/series.rb
class Series
  has_many :timelines
  has_many :creators, through: :contents
end
```

This is not many to many relation, `timelines` table has two fields `creator_id` and `series_id` beside another fields. `creator_id` and `series_id` must be entered when create Timeline and i have a method `series_belongs_to_creator` to validates `series_id` must belong to `creator_id` to create successful.
So how should I write factory for timeline model if using FactoryGirl. Im so confused about Unit test in Rails.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rails 5, you have to keep in mind that `belongs_to` is no longer optional by default: https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html

So `creator_id` will always need to be present unless you specify the relation is optional.

For the factories, you're going to end up with something like this (FactoryGirl was recently renamed to FactoryBot):
http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Associations

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :timeline do
    creator
    series
  end
end


FactoryBot.define do
  factory :creator do
    ...
  end
end


FactoryBot.define do
  factory :series do
    ...
  end
end
```